# What is going on in this recursive Sheme function that doesn't use define?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme

I am reading a book called "The Little Schemer" and in it this piece of code is presented as a recursive way to find the length of a list without having any functions defined.

```
((lambda (mk-length)
       (mk-length mk-length))
     (lambda (mk-length)
       (lambda (l)
         (cond
           ((null? l) 0)
           (else ( add1
                   ((mk-length mk-length)
                     (cdr l))))))))
```

I kind of get the vague idea, that the function is passed a tool to make more of itself, but I keep on confusing myself when I try and fully think through it, and when I try to replicate something like it.

Can someone explain more deeply what is going on here, and why it is so important (the book treated this with a lot of significance)?

Comment: Keep reading, it's explained a bit later. In case it's not yet clear, look for the "Y Combinator", that's the concept that's at play here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try to figure it out yourself by stepping through it with [DrRacket](https://racket-lang.org/)

When opened just paste the code as if it was a function with any list argument, eg.:

```
(((lambda (mk-length)
   (mk-length mk-length))
 (lambda (mk-length)
   (lambda (l)
     (cond
       ((null? l) 0)
       (else ( add1
               ((mk-length mk-length)
                (cdr l))))))))
 '(1 2 3))
```

In the dropdown in the bottom select Choose Language and then in the modal select "Intermediate student with lambda". This is a restricted Scheme with less fancy features than the standard, but your code will work as written. After pressing RUN you'll see a Step button. Press it and you can step through the whole thing visually.

[image: Image of the stepper, showing the very first step!]

This shows the stepper doing the first step.

NB: DrRacket's language "Intermediate student with lambda" may not work on all the code in the book. It's part of the book How to design programs and consist of several languages with different complexity. See the forms allowed in [this documentation page](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/intermediate-lam.html). DrRacket supports the standards R5RS, R6RS, and R7RS is on the way and it also have a naughty non standard implementation by default with the name `#lang racket` which gives you tons of libraries but locks you in to only be able to run in this implementation.